# hello contract: not printing the name

Tags: smart-contract

I just set the hello contract and pushed action hi.
But it did not print the name.

Here is my test command.

```
$cleos --wallet-url http://172.18.0.1:8899 -u http://172.18.0.1:8888 push action shlee hi '["shlee"]' -p shlee@active
executed transaction: a216fd3356d898f9c6bd2fc428df624c9b70f3f5ff2373f227bc68d5e7e5d8ab  104 bytes  261 us
#         shlee <= shlee::hi                    {"user":"shlee"}
2018-12-19T05:54:32.716 thread-0   main.cpp:458                  print_result   warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet
```

Is this normal response?

I was expecting a response like

```
>> Hello, shlee
```

Comment: post your contract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add --contracts-console to your node when launching so that it can print out the "print" in smart-contracts